# Cannot remove nor reinstall Virtualbox on linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04

I've have tried:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Also

```
apt-get clean
```

And I still get output below:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-4.2:i386 : Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 (>= 2:1.02.20) but it is not     installed
                   Depends: libpython2.7:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libqt4-opengl:i386 (>= 4:4.7.2) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 (>= 1.2.10-1) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libxmu6:i386 but it is not installed
                   Depends: psmisc:i386 but it is not installed
                   Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 but it is not installed
                   Recommends: dkms:i386 but it is not installable
                   Recommends: linux-headers:i386
                   Recommends: gcc:i386 but it is not installed
                   Recommends: make:i386 but it is not installed
                   Recommends: binutils:i386 but it is not installed
                   Recommends: pdf-viewer:i386
                   Recommends: python-central:i386 but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: How did you initially install it?

Comment: Have you manually searched for the dependencies (`apt-cache search lib...`)? Though that is strange as I recall libpython being around by default on Ubuntu last time I used it. Your title suggests it's already installed ("can't remove nor..."). Is the current installation broken? Was it ever working? If so, what's changed between the working state and now (upgrades, clean up tools, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
```

If that doesn't work try reinstalling the package headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Also, check out the answer's here:

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: First command outputted: 
    Correcting dependencies... failed. 
    The following packages have unmet dependencies.

Second outputted:
    linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

Comment: @Rafael I updated my answer with a link to a question on the askubuntu forums.  I think you need more than just "one line command" troubleshooting.

Comment: @Colyn1337, it would be too risky to get linux-headers-generic at the first moment.

Comment: @Rafael did you check your linux distro and version and also virtual box package which customized for your linux distro ??

Comment: Thanks for you answers, but I managed it by installing virtualbox using aptitude.